# Cannot load data into a table stored in ORC format

Tags: hive

I'm trying to load data into a `Hive table` stored in the `ORC format`. I use the approach described here: 
[Loading Data from a .txt file to Table Stored as ORC in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive) .
Unfortunately, this method does not work for me. I get the following messages trying to insert data into the table:

> Total MapReduce jobs = 3
>   Launching Job 1 out of 3
>   Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
>   Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
>   Hadoop job information for null: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
>   2014-03-04 16:28:01,497 null map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
>   Ended Job = job_local531196501_0001 with errors
>   Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
>   Execution failed with exit status: 2
>   Obtaining error information
>   
>   Task failed!
>   Task ID:
>     Stage-1

Where can I find the real reason for failure? No logs are mentioned in the output.

Comment: Please give al of your create table statements and your LOAD statements and maybe a small sample of the data.

Comment: Here are all the statements:

create external table rmtail( dm0 int, dm1 int, dm2 int, v1 DOUBLE);

create table dailyaggregations ( dm0 int, dm2 int, v1 DOUBLE)  partitioned by (dm1 int) stored as orc ;  

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dailyaggregations
PARTITION (dm1)
SELECT rm.dm0,rm.dm2,rm.v1,rm.dm1
FROM rmtail rm;

They work find without the "stored as orc" clause.

Comment: Look at your job logs. Location will be entirely dependent on the actual cluster running the job (Hadoop 1.3 vs. Hadoop 2.0/Yarn, Linux vs. Windows  etc etc)

Comment: Try making rmtail a hive managed table and retry with the same code and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I changed the rmtail to be "CREATE TABLE rmtail(...)" and used "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH" to load the data. I still get the same error.

Comment: What is your data size? The job is able to start which means the strategy is working fine for you. However the job is failing due to some reason. One reason could be 'Dynamic Partitions'. Check the size of rmtail table.

Comment: It is not the data size. I figured out that the problem is in the file formats. I try to copy data from a regular table to an ORC file-based one. It does not work. I'm looking for a way to convert a text-based table to an ORC-based one. Nothing works currently.