# Hive error: parseexception missing EOF

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hcatalog

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE default.testtbl(int1 INT,string1 STRING)  
      stored as orc 
      tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE") 
      LOCATION "/user/hive/test_table";

      FAILED: ParseException line 1:107 missing EOF at 'LOCATION' near ')'
```

while the following query works perfectly fine:

```
hive>  CREATE TABLE default.testtbl(int1 INT,string1 STRING)  
       stored as orc 
       tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE");
       OK
       Time taken: 0.106 seconds
```

Am I missing something here. Any pointers will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try put the "LOCATION" in front of "tblproperties" like below, worked for me.

```
CREATE TABLE default.testtbl(int1 INT,string1 STRING)  
  stored as orc 
  LOCATION "/user/hive/test_table"
  tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE");
```

It seems even the sample SQL from book "Programming Hive" got the order wrong. Please reference to the official definition of create table command:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable

Comment: Worked for too... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

@Haiying Wang pointed out that `LOCATION` is to be put in front of `tblproperties`.

But I think the error also occurs when `location` is specified above `stored as`.

Its better to stick to the correct order:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name    -- (Note: TEMPORARY available in Hive 0.14.0 and later)
  [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ... [constraint_specification])]
  [COMMENT table_comment]
  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  [CLUSTERED BY (col_name, col_name, ...) [SORTED BY (col_name [ASC|DESC], ...)] INTO num_buckets BUCKETS]
  [SKEWED BY (col_name, col_name, ...)                  -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.10.0 and later)]
     ON ((col_value, col_value, ...), (col_value, col_value, ...), ...)
     [STORED AS DIRECTORIES]
  [
   [ROW FORMAT row_format] 
   [STORED AS file_format]
     | STORED BY 'storage.handler.class.name' [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)]  -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.6.0 and later)
  ]
  [LOCATION hdfs_path]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, ...)]   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.6.0 and later)
  [AS select_statement];   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.5.0 and later; not supported for external tables)
```

Refer: [Hive Create Table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)

Answer (score 0):

Check this post:

[Loading Data from a .txt file to Table Stored as ORC in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive)

And check your source files present at the specified directory `/user/hive/test_table`. Incase the files are in `.txt` or some other `non ORC` format then you can follow the steps in the above post to come out of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Neels but I am facing the problem while creating a table. I was wondering if the syntax is wrong or there is another condition I need to fulfill in the form of a clause. Correct me if I am wrong, location attribute is for explicitly specifying where to store the table data.

Comment: Can you try if something like this is working for you `CREATE TABLE default.testtbl(int1 INT,string1 STRING)  
      stored as TEXTFILE 
      tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE") 
      LOCATION "/user/hive/test_table"`

Comment: Received the same error: <pre><code>hive> CREATE TABLE default.testtbl(int1 INT,string1 STRING) stored as TEXTFILE tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE") LOCATION "/user/hive/test_table";
FAILED: ParseException line 1:111 missing EOF at 'LOCATION' near ')'

hive>
</code></pre>

Comment: Sorry for the not formatted comment above. The editor isn't letting me edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

**ParseException line lineNumber missing EOF at '.' near 'schemaName':**

Got the above error while trying to execute the following command from linux script to truncate a hive table

*dse -u username -p password hive -e "truncate table keyspace.tablename;"*

**Fix:**
Need to separate the commands within the script line as follows -

*dse -u username -p password hive -e "use keyspace; truncate table keyspace.tablename;"*

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error while creating a table in hive.

I used the drop command to drop the table and then run the create table command that I had again.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error when running the HiveQL from a file with the command "hive -f file.hql". And that it points the first line of your query most definitely this is because of a forgotten semicolon(;) for a previous query.
Since parser looks for semicolon(;) as a terminator for each query. 
for example:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.emp
create table default.emp (
field1 type,
field2 type)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://gts-promocube/source-data/Lowes/POS/';

If you save the above in a file and execute it with hive -f, then you'll get the error:
FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 missing EOF at 'CREATE' near emp.

Solution: Put a semicolon(;) for the DROP TABLE command above.