# How to write the following Query in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I implemented the following query in HIVE:

```
SELECT title, rating FROM 
( 
    SELECT m.title as title, variance(r.rating) as var, r.rating as     rating, r.time_stamp as time_stamp
    FROM movies m JOIN ratings r ON m.movieid = r.movieid
    DISTRIBUTE BY m.title, r.rating
    GROUP BY m.title
    SORT BY m.title, r.rating
) A
WHERE year(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) = '2015'
GROUP BY title
LIMIT 10;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:4 missing ) at 'GROUP' near 'GROUP' line 6:10 missing EOF at 'BY' near 'GROUP'
```

Comment: You have `SELECT m.title as title`, so shouldn't you just GROUP BY title?

Comment: It also does not work with title. The definition title is for the outer select statement

Comment: I'm not seeing why you need to group in the inner query. You're already sorting it, thereby grouping same titles together

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive error: parseexception missing EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463444/hive-error-parseexception-missing-eof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick, it is still SQL.
 - You can't select a column that was not a part of the GROUP BY.
 - `YEAR` returns an integer (P.s. ratings is not partitioned?).
 - You should have a really good reason to use `DISTRIBUTE BY` and `SORT BY`, technical clauses from the beggining time of Hive.

```
select      m.title
           ,r.var

from                   (select      r.movieid
                                   ,variance(r.rating)  as var

                        from        ratings as r

                        where       year(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) = 2015

                        group by    r.movieid

                        order by    var desc

                        limit       10
                        ) as r

            join        movies as m

            on          m.movieid   =
                        r.movieid
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT m.movieid, m.title, variance(r.rating) as var
FROM movies m JOIN
     ratings r
     ON m.movieid = r.movieid
WHERE year(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) = 2015
GROUP BY m.movieid, m.title
ORDER BY var DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . That is true; I chose title because that was how the OP phrased the query.  In any case, I changed it to include `movieId`.