# How do I specify the storage file format as ORCFile using HCatalog?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

HCatalog supports RCFile format, text files, SequenceFiles, or ORC files according to the documentation.

I am not able to find much details on how to specify the storage type in HCatalog as ORCFiles.

Comment: where are you getting the error? In `CREATE` or `INSERT`?

Comment: In CREATE. Basically I am not able to figure out how to specify ORCFile as output format.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive

Comment: Thanks. But I need to programmatically create an ORCFile and load data into it. So I would need to use HCatalog APIs. Although I am able to create a schema, i'm nt sure how to specify the storage format at ORC File.