# How to retrieve data from a specific bucket in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

I created a table in hive

```
create table HiveMB 
  (EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int,Department String)
   clustered by (Department) into 3 buckets 
   stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true') ;
```

where my file format is like

```
1,Anne,Admin,50000,A
2,Gokul,Admin,50000,B
3,Janet,Sales,60000,A
4,Hari,Admin,50000,C
5,Sanker,Admin,50000,C
```

and the data went into 3 buckets for department.

When I examined the warehouse , there are 3 buckets

```
Found 3 items
-rwxr-xr-x   3 aibladmin hadoop     252330 2014-11-28 14:46 /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb/delta_0000012_0000012/bucket_00000
-rwxr-xr-x   3 aibladmin hadoop     100421 2014-11-28 14:45 /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb/delta_0000012_0000012/bucket_00001
-rwxr-xr-x   3 aibladmin hadoop     313047 2014-11-28 14:46 /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb/delta_0000012_0000012/bucket_00002
```

How will I be able to retrieve 1 such bucket.

When I did a `-cat`, It is not in human readable format.
showing something like

```
`J�ǉ�(��rwNj��[��Y���gR�� \�B�Q_Js)�6 �st�A�6�ixt� R �
ޜ�KT� e����IL Iԋ� ł2�2���I�Y��FC8 /2�g� ����� > ������q�D � b�` `�`���89$ $$ ����I��y|@޿    
                                                                                                %\���� �&�ɢ`a~ � S �$�l�:y���K $�$����X�X��)Ě���U*��
6.  �� �cJnf� KHjr�ć����� ��(p` ��˻_1s  �5ps1:  1:I4L\��u
```

How can I able to see the data stored into each bucket?

And my file is in csv format not ORC so as a workaround I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive)

But I am not able to view data in buckets. That is not in human readable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am uploading orc screen shot which was produce from this hive queries:

```
create table stackOverFlow 
(EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int,Department String)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';

load data local inpath '/home/ravi/stack_file.txt'
overwrite into table stackOverFlow;
```

and

```
  create table stackOverFlow6
(EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int,Department String)
   clustered by (Department) into 3 buckets
   row format delimited
   fields terminated by ','
stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");
 insert overwrite table stackOverFlow6 select * from stackOverFlow;
```

generated ORC result file for above hive queries:
[image]

Comment: Are we not able to see this data in human readable format? and if we need to enter data/record into ORC table, That data should be in that format. Is that necessary?

Comment: **ORC** format has  different types and i used **"orc.compress"="ZLIB"** so i got this one(previous pic), and its not necessary as shown in pic, but ORC gives us to compressed large  data into small data file. Suppose 585 GB text file to  131 GB ORCFile, and it having many best future like storage data prospective etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table HiveMB1 
  (EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int,Department String)
 row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';

load data local inpath '/home/user17/Data/hive.txt'
overwrite into table HiveMB1;


create table HiveMB2
(EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int,Department String)
   clustered by (Department) into 3 buckets
   row format delimited
   fields terminated by ',';

 insert overwrite table HiveMB2 select * from HiveMB1 ;



user17@BG17:~$ hadoop dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 user17 supergroup         22 2014-12-01 15:52 /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2/000000_0
-rw-r--r--   1 user17 supergroup         44 2014-12-01 15:53 /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2/000001_0
-rw-r--r--   1 user17 supergroup         43 2014-12-01 15:53 /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2/000002_0

user17@BG17:~$ hadoop dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2/000000_0
2,Gokul,Admin,50000,B

user17@BG17:~$ hadoop dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2/000001_0
4,Hari,Admin,50000,C
5,Sanker,Admin,50000,C

user17@BG17:~$ hadoop dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/hivemb2/000002_0
1,Anne,Admin,50000,A
3,Janet,Sales,60000,A
```

Answer (score 0):

your table:

```
> create table HiveMB 
  (EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int,Department String)
   clustered by (Department) into 3 buckets 
   stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true') ;
```

you are chosen table as a `ORC` format, which means it compresses actual the data and stores the compressed data.

Comment: Could you pls help me with a sample ORC format file?

Comment: My file is in csv format and as a workaround I loaded csv to orc table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive

Comment: ` CREATE TABLE ORCFileFormatExample(
        tweet_id INT, username BIGINT,
        txt STRING, Created_at STRING,
        profile_location STRING,
        favc INT,no_of_retweets STRING,retcount INT,followers_count INT)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");`

Comment: how an orc file looks like, do u have any sample entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the orc format for a bucket by the command :

```
hive --orcfiledump [path-to-the-bucket]
```