# Loading data from a txt table into orc table HIVE- Query

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

my main aim is to create a table which is stored as ORC . For that, I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive)

I have created a folder **/user/hive/external** and created both the tables (**table_txt** & **table_orc**) in the same location. Till loading the data in table_txt, its fine.

Now , what I found is , when I move the data from table_txt to table_orc using

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_orc SELECT * FROM table_txt;
```

the tables from the path */external are removed ( as viewed on web UI) and now I have a file named like " 000000_0 " and on clicking on it, i get some encoded stuff.

The questions--

1- What is this 000000_0 file and why are not the tables visible on web UI

2- When I query table_txt, why doesn't it give any data? whereas on querying table_orc, I get results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> created both tables ... in the same location  ==>  *RED FLAG!!!*

It is the **location** that defines which data files belong to which table. In other words, every table should be located on a *private directory*.

So the `INSERT OVERWRITE` removed everything in the *private directory* of your ORC table, then created a new data file -- in ORC binary format. That's the expected behaviour. Too bad the TXT files were there, too.

By the way, one a the differences between an "external" and a "managed" table is that when you `drop` a managed table, the whole directory is destroyed, while dropping an external table leaves the data as-is.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I tried with separate directories of the tables. And works like a charm! :) thanks