# Unable to load text data into Hive table as ORC through temporary Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-manager, orc, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I want to load `.csv` file into Hive table as a ORC file. I came across one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive) 
which suggested a workaround to the problem to which I executed the below queries:

**1) Creating and loading data as a text file into a temporary table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CrimesData( ID int, Case_Number int, CrimeDate string, Block string , IUCR string,Primary_Type string, Description string, Location_Description string, Arrest string, Domestic string, Beat int, District int, Ward int, Community_Area int, FBI_Code string, X_Coordinate int, Y_Coordinate int, Year int, Updated_On string, Latitude decimal(10,10), Longitude decimal(10,10), CrimeLocation string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/Documents/CrimesData.csv' INTO TABLE CrimesData
```

**2) Creating a new table and specifying ORC data as the source:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CrimesDataORC( ID int, Case_Number int, CrimeDate string, Block string , IUCR string,Primary_Type string, Description string, Location_Description string, Arrest string, Domestic string, Beat int, District int, Ward int, Community_Area int, FBI_Code string, X_Coordinate int, Y_Coordinate int, Year int, Updated_On string, Latitude decimal(10,10), Longitude decimal(10,10), CrimeLocation string) 
STORED AS ORC;
```

**3) Insert data into the new table from temporary table:**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE CrimesDataORC SELECT * FROM CrimesData;
```

The first two steps execute without any error but the step 3 throws the following error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

I am running the above queries on Cloudera Manager Quickstart VM 5.8.

Not sure where I am going wrong as similar steps for another table in the same database works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It might be kind of data non-compliance with structure. Try to set some where conditions in the select statement to check rather inserting all the data

Comment: Thank you for the suggesting, I'll try it out and update if that works or not.. 

Comment: Tried executing: 
INSERT INTO TABLE CrimesDataORC SELECT * FROM CrimesData LIMIT 10;
But that too didn't work out.. :(