# Loading CSV data into Hive ORC tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, sandbox, hue

I have data as below:

```
id,name,description,category
1,sid,I am don,right?,production
```

I followed the steps provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721251/loading-data-from-a-txt-file-to-table-stored-as-orc-in-hive) link. The main problem is when I insert the data into the temp table, data in the `3rd column` gets separated and pushed into the 4th column i.e when it sees `","` before `right` word it divides the data and pushes it into the next column. It is because I am getting data in CSV format and hence applying delimiter as `","` while creating a temp table. So, there is a mess. How can I resolve it ??

After following steps suggested by `xenodevil`, I ran below query and I am getting error:

```
insert into perTable select * from sampleTable;
```

Where sampleTable is the temp table and perTable is the ORC table and sampleTable data looks as below:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+--+
| sampletable.id  | sampletable.name  | sampletable.description  | sampletable.category  |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+--+
| 1               | sid               | I am don,right?          | production            |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+--+
```

But getting below error:

```
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1560140822404_0022_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1560140822404_0022_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"id":"1","name":"sid","description":"I am don,right?","category":"production"}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
```

So what is the issue over here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you going to determine how many commas are coming in 3rd column? If it can contain any text, then it can contain any number of commas. This must be controlled at the file generation level, i.e. when your data is being written rather that when you are trying to read it at a later time in CSV format. While generating the CVS file, you may

- Put a escape character before each comma which is part of data rather than a comma delimiter
- Enclose each column's text in double quotes
- Enclose only the columns where delimiting character (comma) is present with double quotes

These are some of the common practices which reliably resolve such issues.

An unreliable way, very specific to data you have presented, and which will resolve only redundant commas in your 3rd column is to use following RegexSerDe for your ROW FORMAT

```
([0-9]*),([a-zA-Z ]*),([A-Za-z ,?]*),([A-Za-z ,]*)
```

To set this, you will need to modify the table's DDL to something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `your_database_name.your_table_name`(
    `id` string,
    `name` string,
    `description` string,
    `category` string
)
COMMENT 'Your Comment'
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'input.regex'='([0-9]*),([a-zA-Z ]*),([A-Za-z ,?]*),([A-Za-z ,]*)'
 )
STORED AS TEXT
;
```

I have checked the Regex here, but you will need to adjust the DDL syntax to suite your needs.

Comment: Okay let me check this one

Comment: Suppose I have 40 columns so in that case my regex would change ?

Comment: What is the significance of this regex ([A-Za-z ,?]*),([A-Za-z ,]*) ? Does it mean data containing ","

Comment: yes, you will need to modify the regex. Meaning of `([A-Za-z ,?]*),([A-Za-z ,]*)` is zero of more characters of any small and capital letter from A to Z, comma and question mark and then match another similar pattern.

Comment: Idea is to match one column which may contain zero or more characters (this is specified by `*` in the regex), then a comma and then same type of characters in the second column which again may contain zero or more characters of data. Square brackets specify patterns, parenthesis specify which matched patterns are picked by Hive as column values. Since comma is not in parenthesis, it does not fall into any column and this is what we require. Regex is a huge and immensely useful topic. It can be generally suggested to get familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: I followed your steps and I am getting an error as posted in the question. Could you please help me with that

Comment: Most likely the data does not fit into the structure/examples you have given. As I said, this is a bad way of solving delimiter issues. The regular expression must match the data which is being parsed. The regular expression i shared works for the examples your presented, but it may not work on any other anomalies in your data, causing errors during run time. Vertexes may also fail for a number of other reasons. Try disabling vectorization in Hive configurations and re-execute your jobs. It may help with identifying the real error.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. I created both temp and permanent tables with regex serde where I just had to make temp table with regex serde. I dropped permanent table and created fresh orc permanent table and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample flow to load data in a Hive table.

1) Since there is ambiguity related the `,` delimiter, update the file to have a delimiter of `|` that identifies actual fields. So, the file looks like this. Let's call this `data.csv`.

```
1|sid|I am don,right?|production
```

2) Create a table in `Hive`, specifying the correct column delimiter.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE t1_tmp
(
    id string,
    name string,
    description string,
    category string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

3) Load the data from the local file

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/path/to/data.csv' INTO TABLE t1_tmp;
```

4) View the data

```
hive> select * from t1_tmp;
OK
t1_tmp.id   t1_tmp.name t1_tmp.description  t1_tmp.category
1           sid         I am don,right?     production
```

Comment: I can't replace delimiter

Comment: Coz If i use replace function it will replace all the commas

Comment: You can try to modify the logic that generates the CSV file to output `|` delimiter instead of `,`.

Comment: I am using HUE and there is no such option available

Comment: Try logging in with SSH and execute `hdfs dfs -put "local_file_name" "hdfs_file_name"` to load a file from local system to HDFS. Using Hue will not get you anywhere good in this resolving this issue.